# Transaction in Uncommited isolation level

Tags: sql, database, isolation-level

Can a transaction write to the database if its isolation level is set to uncommitted read?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server yes, but the DML statements take normal locks even for reading data, so really don’t run in READ UNCOMMITTED.